# What do (R) and (Z) mean in chemical names?

Tags: notation

So, I'm confused on the notation my professor uses in a certain question; could someone explain. 
He says:

Draw the structure: (R)-(Z)-chloro-4,6,-dimethyl-3-octene

I get everything after '(z)'

I'm just unsure what he means by '(R)-(Z)'...

Any input is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: For R read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality_%28chemistry%29#By_configuration:_R-_and_S-) and for Z [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-Z_notation).

Comment: The proper name should, however, be (3 _Z_ , 6 _R_ )-1-chloro-4,6-dimethyloct-3-ene.

Comment: @Martin Is it necessary here. I mean it has only one place for Z abd T and only one chiral centre

Comment: @DSinghvi I was merely stating the proper IUPAC recommended name. If they make more or less sense is up to everyone else to consider.

Answer (score 6):

The name (*R*,*Z*)-chloro-4,6-dimethyloct-3-ene is ambiguous. This could be (*R*,*Z*)-1-chloro-4,6-dimethyloct-3-ene, (*R*,*Z*)-3-chloro-4,6-dimethyloct-3-ene, (*R*,*Z*)-6-chloro-4,6-dimethyloct-3-ene, or (*R*,*Z*)-8-chloro-4,6-dimethyloct-3-ene. (2-chloro-4,6-dimethyloct-3-ene, 5-chloro-4,6-dimethyloct-3-ene, and 7-chloro-4,6-dimethyloct-3-ene have one additional stereocenter.) For example:

[image: (R,Z)-1-chloro-4,6-dimethyloct-3-ene]